# How to sync my PDA (outlook, no wifi) with my Google Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar, pda

We have an old PDA that is not networked (Mio 168). It's main purpose is to serve as an agenda for which we use the outlook that came with it.

Now, as my wife usually has the PDA and I want to be able to check and update our agenda too, I'm looking for a way to sync it with Google Calendar by hooking it to my PC via USB.

I found a tool to sync outlook with Google Calendar. However, I would need outlook on my PC to be able to use that and I don't have outlook on my PC, nor do I want to buy it just for this sync.

So, does anybody here now if and how I can sync my outlook on my PDA with Google Calendar without the go between of a PC version of outlook?

Cheers.

Comment: Super User is intended for computer hardware and software related questions only. Web services, such as Google's services, sync between mobile devices and web services, are considered off-topic. Please see the FAQ ( http://superuser.com/faq )

Comment: synchronizing PDA devices via a computer is on topic here.  even if trying to sync to a web service, you need something to install on the local computer to glue the two together.  @Sathya

Comment: @quack quixote OP is trying to eliminate the PC factor, thereby making this a sync between a mobile device and a web service,which makes the question offtopic. Anyhow if you feel this question is on-topic *shrugs*.

Comment: it(ie the faq) is dumb that this is even close to off topic.

Comment: @sathya: he's trying to avoid *outlook* on the PC, which i find completely understandable.

Comment: @Sathya, quick on the draw to shoot someone's question out of the water. As my PDA is not networked, clearly described, I can't eliminate the PC, and don't want too for that matter. Just trying to get around the outlook bit.

Answer (score 1):

I am using http://nuevasync.com/ as ActiveSync server; probably Google gives also the same service on its own, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Google Sync for Windows Mobile Phone](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138636&topic=14299), which uses ActiveSync and can connect via Wifi or through a host computer via a USB cable. Should work on any device that uses Windows Mobile or Pocket PC.

Comment: Great, this could be what I'm looking for!
Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: No luck,
I can use my PC with the "Sync Center" software to set & test the google sync setup perfectly, but if I try to actually sinc, I get an Error Code: DEV_9. As far as I can see, the mobile device ruins the password time after time, hence the credentials error.

Comment: Make sure the username is ____@gmail.com. You may also need to set the domain to "google" as per http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=41c127cb08ab66ac&hl=en